# Making a vector of linked lists?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

How can I make a vector of linked lists?

For example I have a struct of properties (for the linked-list) defined as follows:

```
typedef struct property {
    string info;
    property* implication;
} property;
```

And then I have a class object:

```
class objects {
private:
    vector<property> *traits;
public:
    void giveProperty(property *x) {
    traits.push_back(&x);
    }
};
```

Where what I want to do conceptually is give an object certain properties, and each property has a series of implications (which is the linked list) which I can use later. But I am getting the error:

> request for member 'push_back' in '((objects*)this)->objects::traits', which is of non-class type 'std::vector >*'

I am having trouble getting this to work. Sorry if this is unclear, if you have questions I will try clarifying myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in class `objects`, you have declared a *pointer* to a vector of properties, when really you want a vector of *property pointers*:

```
class objects {
private:
    vector<property*> traits;    // Note where * is
public:
    void giveProperty(property *x) {
        traits.push_back(x);    // Note that x is already a pointer, no need to take its address
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are using raw pointers. You say you want to have a linked list, but you don't implement that anywhere. Why not use the `std::list` container for your linked lists and lose the pointers altogether?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::list;

struct implication {
    implication(string name) : name(name) {}
    string name;
};

struct property {
    property(string info) : info(info) {}
    string info;
    list<implication> implList;
};

class object {
private:
    vector<property> traits;
public:
    void giveProperty(const property& x) {
        traits.push_back(x);
    }
};

int f() {
    object o;
    property p1("p1");
    property p2("p2");
    implication i("implic");

    p1.implList.push_back(i);
    p1.implList.push_back(implication("other implic"));

    o.giveProperty(p1);

    o.giveProperty(property("p3"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
vector<property> *traits;
```

to

```
vector<property*>  traits; // Needs to be the declaration.
```

Since you are trying to `push_back` addresses to the vector `traits`.

```
void giveProperty(property *x) {
    traits.push_back(&x);
                     ^ Error : With the above modifications made, traits can hold
                       elements of type property*. By doing &x, you are trying to do
                       push_back pointer's address which in that case vector should
                       hold elements of type property**. So, just remove the & 
                       symbol before x while push_back because x is already of type
                       property*

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
traits.push_back(&x);
```

to this:

```
traits->push_back(*x);
```

---

Or probably/possibly, you would want to change this:

```
vector<property> *traits;
```

to this:

```
vector<property*> traits;
```

I would go for the latter one!

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting an error: `no matching function for call to 'std::vector<property*, std::allocator<property*> >::push_back(property**)'` After doing both changes.

Comment: @anon: NO. Change either first or second. NOT both. I didn't say, change both. I said "change this to that" OR "this to that"

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what pointers are?

```
vector<property*> *traits;
```

You're creating a pointer to a vector, not a vector. You would need to create one:

```
traits = new vector<property*>;
```

then access it as:

```
traits->push_back(x);
```